# Put hangout in AIR inApp

Tags: flash, air

I'm trying to make an Flash Adobe AIR app that integrates with google hangout. Is it possible to make the hangout ui to be INSIDE the Air app?
So far i can come with is a button that open a new window for hangout. Any suggestion or pointers?

Answer (score 0):

No. All hangouts open in a new window or new tab.